# Is it possible to export the data from multiple pictures in a data excel sheet?

Tags: excel, image, search, getimagedata, datasheet

I got 1500 old books and i want to sell them all.
I got from every book a picture but not al the information.
I want to make a data sheet from al the books with pictures, names and author.

My question;
Is it possible to bulk import the pictures in a software/something or google lens kinda stuff and get al the data in a excel sheet?

and what do i need for it?

i tried to import more pictures in google lens but that doesn't work.
I tried to search to export the data but i founded nothing.

Comment: Yes it's possible through the use of an image processing library to read the book name, author name from the pictures. Emgu CV is a good starting library.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to look further into it the next few days.